# Network Manager bug Debian 12

Tags: debian, networkmanager

[image]I have gnome verison of Debian 12, and every time i restart system, network manager status icon says i am online, but after few seconds(refreshing) it says offline (?)symbol. when i restar NetworkManager it is ok till next reboot. I tried to set network config managed=true but same thing happens..even i tried cron to set to automatically reset network adapter upon boot, but that dosent work either. I use Ethernet connection..is there anyone who fixed this? or haveing same issue..internet works only status icon says it is offline..i tried many things in order to fix that but with no luck so far..any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have the package named `network-manager-config-connectivity-debian` installed? It includes a configuration file `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-debian.conf` that tells NetworkManger to perform connectivity checks by trying to access this URL: http://network-test.debian.org/nm

The response from that URL should include the HTTP header `X-NetworkManager-Status: online`, or the body of the response should be only the text `NetworkManager is online`. Currently, the response available from that URL will satisfy both conditions.

Either make sure you are not blocking access to that URL, or simply remove that package from your system.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that package wasnt installed on my system i checked..